# Putting the elements of a list inside another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list `list1 = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and want to put the elements of this list inside a list of 0's, `list2 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, where each element of `list1` will be in the position represented by the previous element, so for instance I will put 1 in position 6 of `list2`, 3 in position 1 of `list2`, 4 in position 3 of `list2`, and so on.

In the end, I would like to get a list of the form `{3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. Is it possible to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Something like `ReplacePart[list2, Thread[RotateRight[list1] -> list1]]`?

Comment: Am I missing the gist of the question, or `list2[[RotateRight@list1]] = list1;` does what you want.

Comment: I want to do this in a more general way and put it inside a function, so I haven't been able to use list2[[RotateRight@list1]] = list1; inside the function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `fn=Function[{l2, l1}, l2[[RotateRight@l1]] = l1; l2, HoldFirst];` then `fn[list2,list1]` to use is one way.

Comment: `SparseArray[RotateRight[list1] -> list1, Length[list2]]`, apply `Normal` to it to get a dense array.